# changing string value displayed in scrollView

Tags: android, string, layout

first I would like to say thank you to every one out here as i am a nOOb and have learned a lot just by reading questions and answers that you post. I am trying to pass a great deal of text to the end users and while being able to do this with new classes and .xml files this is becoming cumbersome. i thought of stream lining the app by just having a single xml layout for a particular set of text strings and just change the @string/????? via button onclick and setText but have learned that I can not change the initial value of @string in an xml file. question is that TRUE? and is there a more efficient way to do this ie (setting android:text to a var and setting var in java to a particular string) or do i need a new xml layout for each string? (that's a lots of waste if you ask me) and a little insight, there are at this time approx 250 different strings with min 5 paragraphs and growing.

here is my code thus far.

snippet of first java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Monlt extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.monolt);


    final MediaPlayer buttonsound = MediaPlayer.create(Monlt.this, (R.raw.buttonclick));


            Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(id.button1);
            Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(id.button2);
            Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(id.button3);
            Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(id.button4);
            Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(id.button5);
            Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(id.button6);
            Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(id.button7);
            Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(id.button8);
            Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(id.button9);
            Button button11 = (Button) findViewById(id.button11);
            Button button12 = (Button) findViewById(id.button12);
            Button button13 = (Button) findViewById(id.button13);
            Button button14 = (Button) findViewById(id.button14);
            Button button15 = (Button) findViewById(id.button15);
            Button button16 = (Button) findViewById(id.button16);
            Button button17 = (Button) findViewById(id.button17);
            Button button18 = (Button) findViewById(id.button18);
            Button button19 = (Button) findViewById(id.button19);
            Button button21 = (Button) findViewById(id.button21);

            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    buttonsound.start();
                    final TextView mview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solayout2); 
                    mview.setText("mono1"); //this was my first string to pass
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.nvar.Sorders.Mono.ASO1"));

                }

            });

            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    buttonsound.start();
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.nvar.Sorders.ASO1"));
                    final TextView mview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solayout2); 
                    mview.setText("@string/mono2");/this is the second string to pass
                }
            });
                `
```

now this code works when i remove the 2 text view lines in the onclick 
so then it call another class Aso1 that I would like to keep in place for later use. 
Aso1 java code
`
    package com.nvar.Sorders.Mono;

```
import com.nvar.Sorders.R;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Aso1 extends Activity   {



// Called when the activity is first created.
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.solayout2);


}
}
```

`

and then the first xml

`

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/solayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="mview"/>

 <!--            android:text="@string/monoaso1"/>   
 -->
 <!--  this is were i was playing with the strings  />
 -->        


    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

`
any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated, and remember "noob" to java / android! so if there is a sample of what i could or should be looking at, don't hesitate to smack me in the head and point me in the right direction. i don't mind reading :) 
thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

*@string/string_name* in xml are not designed to change the value. They are there to help you with localization. Currently that xml is located here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

```
res/values/string.xml
```

you can have another string xml with different language like in the following location, for example france

```
res/values-fr/strings.xml
```

you can read more about that over [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Now, let's move on to how to reference that string_name from java

```
Resources res = Monlt.this.getResources();
mview.setText(res.getString(R.string.string_name)); 
//do something
mview.setText(res.getString(R.string.mono2));
```

Comment: noting that i am starting a new activity and opening a new class and xml after the on click, when i use the setText i get a runtime error. if i remove that line the app will proceed to next class and new xml. i am not sure if i dont understand the answer or i failed to explain the question. i do not wish to change to values of a string i just wish to show a different string according to the option selected in the onClick in the first class.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add localization link for the string xml usage. I have updated the code to change the text as well. so you need to declare two sting values in xml and you can always get their string values using the `res.getString(R.string.string_id)`

Answer (score 0):

When displaying the `String`s, What you could use is a `TextView` and have multiple lines and then just update the text value of it in code. It doesn't even need default text

```
<ScrollView
    ...some params...>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="10"/>
</ScrollView>
```

This will give you a `TextView` 10 lines long. Then in code you can do something like this to update the value:

```
String longText = getVeryLongText();
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text)).setText(longText);
```

Then you'll have something that looks like a scrollable paragraph of text